# Doing like if it was a table with a div

Tags: html, css

Here what I have :

```
<div id="my_div">
<a href='#'>Link 1</a>
<a href='#'>Link 2</a>
<a href='#'>Link 3</a>
<a href='#'>Link 4</a>
<a href='#'>Link 5</a>
<a href='#'>Link 6</a>
<a href='#'>Link 7</a>
<a href='#'>Link 8</a>
<a href='#'>Link 9</a>
<a href='#'>Link 10</a>
</div>
```

I would like the HTML page to look as follow :

```
Link 1 Link 2
Link 3 Link 4
Link 5 Link 6
Link 7 Link 8
Link 9 Link 10
```

Or, if I want elements 3 by 3 :

```
Link 1 Link 2 Link 3
Link 4 Link 5 Link 6
Link 7 Link 8 Link 9
Link 10
```

How to play with CSS to achieve this ?

I would like to put a picture inside each link (to have sort of buttons with picture and text)

So my `a` elements might have some width, padding, etc.

Comment: eehm? use a table.....

Comment: I want to keep it dynamic, if I remove one link.

Comment: And to be able to change how many elements by line.

Comment: set `width:100px` `height:100px` `float:left` and `display:block` to `.a` and to your div `width:300px` (if you want 3 per row)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yfrep168/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

### [**THIS ONE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/nrzzu9z9/1/)

```
#my_div a:nth-child(odd) {
   clear: left;
}

#my_div a {
     float: left;
}

#my_div2 a:nth-child(3n+1) {
   clear: left;
}

#my_div2 a {
     float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) in the demo, what is the explanation for "<div class="cf"></div>". Why a div in a div ? Why doesn't it works when I put the div with cf between the two div ?

Answer (score 2):

> [**CSS Multi-column Layout Module**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#introduction)
>
> This module describes multi-column layout in CSS. By using
>   functionality described in this document, style sheets can declare
>   that the content of an element is to be laid out in multiple columns.
>   On the Web, tables have also been used to describe multi-column
>   layouts. The main benefit of using CSS-based columns is flexibility;
>   content can flow from one column to another, and the number of columns
>   can vary depending on the size of the viewport. Removing presentation
>   table markup from documents allows them to more easily be presented on
>   various output devices including speech synthesizers and small mobile
>   devices.

If using [CSS multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) is an option you can achieve the layout simply as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/zekage/1/edit)**

```css
#my_div {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;

  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-gap: 2em;
}

#my_div > a { display: block; }
```

While it is well supported by Firefox, Chrome/Safari, it [won't work on IE9 and below](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) which may or may not meet your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, multi-column layouts are not as well implemented as they should be (even in Firefox and webkit-based browsers). So for this task I'd stick with traditional approaches.

Comment: @raina77ow So do I. However `Two decades of layout hacks are coming to an end. Maybe not tomorrow, but soon` — CSS Legendary Eric Meyer

Comment: I really wish multi-column layouts were the answer, believe me, I do. But while working on reflowable views for EPUBs I found as many bugs in their implementation as I would never have dared to imagine. ) The problem is, in my understanding, that spec itself is too fragile at this point.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%; // 49% for 2 columns, etc.
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oockoqyz/).

Comment: a fixed height *may* be used with this too

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/cxdaraaj/)

[image]

```
a{width:50%;}
a:nth-child(-n+5) {
    float:left;   
}
a:nth-child(n+6) {
    float:right;   
}
```

or

```
a{width:50%;}
a:nth-child(odd) {
    float:left;   
}
a:nth-child(even) {
    float:right;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
a:nth-child(odd){
    clear: left;
}

a{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o1x2x5w9/1/)

Or if you want elements 3 by 3:

```
a:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear: left;
}

a{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o1x2x5w9/3/)